Raspberry PI (CM4) video to USB-C DisplayPort alt mode
I'm working on a project where I aim to utilize a USB-C port to embed both video signals and USB functionality. USB-C's "Alt Modes" offer potential solutions, namely DisplayPort (DP) Alt Mode and HDMI Alt Mode, with the former being the more commonly supported. For instance, touchscreens like the Verbatim PMT-15 support USB-C DisplayPort Alt Mode but not HDMI Alt Mode.
Here's where I'm facing a challenge: the Raspberry Pi CM4, which I intend to use, provides HDMI and DSI video outputs but lacks DisplayPort. I’ve searched for an easy-to-implement IC for DP to HDMI conversion without much luck—the STDP4028-AB from Kinetic Technologies is an option but it's outdated.
One option I considered is the TUSB546A, which could mux HDMI and USB 3.1 Gen 1, but it seems DP controllers typically don't support HDMI Alt Mode. Another possibility was the ANX7625 (MIPI-DSI/DPI to USB Type-C™ Bridge), though its sourcing seems limited.
Here's a summary of the situation:

The preferred method for carrying a video stream over USB-C to a touchscreen is through DP Alt Mode.
The Raspberry Pi (specifically CM4) only has HDMI or DSI/MIPI outputs.
Finding a straightforward HDMI to DP conversion solution has proven difficult.

How do I connect a Raspberry Pi CM4 to a touchscreen using USB-C, factoring in the limitations and options mentioned above?
